# How can I skip a migration with Django migrate command?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

First, I am asking about Django migration introduced in 1.7, not `south`.

Suppose I have migrations `001_add_field_x`, `002_add_field_y`, and both of them are applied to database. Now I change my mind and decide to revert the second migration and replace it with another migration `003_add_field_z`.

In other words, I want to apply 001 and 003, skipping 002, how can I do this?

P.S. I know I can migrate backwards to 001, but after I make the 003 migration and execute migrate command, 001 through 003 will all be applied, right?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can use the `--fake` option.

Once you revert to `0001` you can run

```
python manage.py migrate <app> 0002 --fake
```

and then run

```
python manage.py migrate <app> #Optionally specify 0003 explicitly
```

which would apply only `0003` in this case.

If you do not want to follow this process for all the environment/other developers, you can just remove the migration files, and run a new `makemigration`, and commit that file - and yes, do run `migrate` with the `--fake` option

docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake

Answer (score 7):

Not applicable to this specific case, but if one wants or needs to skip **all** unapplied migrations, this can be used:

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Just saves a bit of typing.