# Creating a .gitignore file for a Django website

Tags: python, django, git, gitignore

I'm ready to push my existing Django project (which i've been running in a local environment) to a Bitbucket repository so I can run it on a public server. At the moment I feel like there's a lot of files created in local development that needs to be added to `.gitignore`.

I found [this `.gitignore` file on github](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore) however I still feel it's missing some things, for example it doesn't seem to remove files from each `migrations` folders. There's also a lot of stuff there that I don't know what they do - I understand not all of it is needed. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: you think you don't need to run migrations on public server?

Comment: No I'm referring to the migration files inside the `migrations` folders. When I start development I need them to be empty to start afresh.

Answer (score 21):

You could consider a [`gitignore` tailored for Django project](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/.gitignore) instead.

And don't forget that, if you already have added and committed a folder content, you will need to remove them before your .gitignore  can take effect.

```
git rm --cached -r afolder/
```

However, by default, `migration` is not ignored. (you can [skip some of those migration steps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31369466/6309))
As pointed out by [Ora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9032857/ora) in the comments, see "[Should I be adding the Django migration files in the `.gitignore` file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28035119/6309)".

So, do not add `migration/` to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: you should not ignore the migrations.  see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035119/should-i-be-adding-the-django-migration-files-in-the-gitignore-file

Comment: @Ora I know: I was editing the answer to that effect.

Comment: Sorry I'm abit confused - are you saying to not add any pattern in `.gitignore` to block the `migrations` content, so to simply remove them after pushing them to the repo? by using `git rm --cached -r migration/`? @VonC

Comment: You shouldn't remove them at all. They are part of your codebase.

Comment: @Zorgan Yes, don't remove them. My remark was more generic about the case where a `.gitignore` seems to "not work". I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

The best example I have found is here: https://djangowaves.com/tips-tricks/gitignore-for-a-django-project/

This is not my work!!!  I don't want to take credit for someone else's good collection!  Not everything in there is relevant.  The author documents it well, though, so you can boil it down to what you need.

I would also add:

```
**/migrations
*.DS_Store
**/__pycache__
**/.DS_Store
```

Comment: migrations are supposed to be shipped, why would you ignore these?

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't know how did you add `migrations` directories. If you already committed to git with those directories, then simply add `migrations/*` to `.gitignore` and delete all the migrations folder. Then commit and push. After this, you will never see any `migrations` changes to git until you forcefully staged and commit.